# how to do arithmatic operations in linux using awk or sed and piping the result to a file

Tags: linux, awk, arithmetic-expressions

with this problem I am beating my head with walls, please help.

I have two files  Sheetthickness.k which contains a single value of initial thickness and minThick.k  which contains the final thickness only a single number.  I want to calculate the percentage decrease in thickness so I used.

```
fina="$(cat minThick.k)";
echo $fina
init="$(cat Sheetthickness.k)";
echo $init 

echo |awk "{ print ($init-$fina)/($init) }" > LSDynaResponse.txt
```

In shell where there is no other command and the files are already there then it works perfectly , but when the  files are created by a software and then these commands are used, it gives error.

```
awk: { print (-)/() }  
awk:           ^ syntax error
awk: { print (-)/() }
awk:            ^ syntax error
awk: { print (-)/() }
awk:             ^ unterminated regexp
```

Any other elegant way to do this task?

Comment: @perreal: That is incorrect. You either need to use `echo` to give AWK something via `stdin` to consume or do the calculation in a `BEGIN` block. Otherwise it will hang waiting for intput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have empty files or no files at all, try like this:

```
fina="$(cat minThick.k)"       || echo "No min file!!"
[[ -z $fina ]]                 && echo "Null min value!!"
echo $fina
init="$(cat Sheetthickness.k)" || echo "No init file!!"
[[ -z $init ]]                 && echo "Null init value!!"
echo $init
echo "($init-$fina)/($init)"   | bc -l > LSDynaResponse.txt
```